# Calculate overall spendings in the last year

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("21.1.13","31.3.13","12.4.13","1.6.13","1.1.14",
"19.2.14","27.2.14","2.10.14","31.10.14","21.11.14"),  
price = c(9.99, 5.49, 7.99, 9.99, 19.99, 9.99, 4.99, 29.99, 9.99, 4.99), 
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

Expected outcome:(actual date in example = 19.12.2014)

```
 Totalspendingspercustomerlastyear = c(34.97, 34,98, 9.99, 34.97, 34.97, 9.99, 
      34,98, 34,98, 34.97, 34.97)
```

Hey guys,

I want to calculate the total spendings per customer over the last year (time period from 19.12.2013-2014 today; tomorrow 20.12.2013-20.12.2014): it should work with the actual system time - 1year. I tried out something already with `Sys.Date()` and the `lubridate` package: but I was not able to manage it...hope you guys are able to help me with it...

Thanks already!

Comment: Show your work. (And use `library() calls to load packages. That way you can clean up the errors in your spelling when they error out.)

Comment: actualDate <- Sys.Date()
format(actualDate, "%Y-%m-%d") 
Test <- ifelse(DB1$orderDate != actualDate, DB1[c("Testi")] <- "Yes",  DB1[c("Testi")] <- "No")

Comment: But of course it´s not working-it´s just a test...Both of your answers are definately not working:the period of the last your is dynamic(changing every day): thought that the data set and expected output is selfexplaining...

Answer (score 0):

Another piece of the answer might be making the date reference dynamic with something like

```
today <- as.POSIXct( strftime( Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d") )
```

followed by

```
...
filter(orderDate > today) %>% 
...
```